# Subscribing observable which has self-reference property

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a class that store time information and my server will return timestamp to me. So I want to format and display date.

```
export class Product {
    timeCreated: number;

    // this don't work
    get timeCreatedDisplay () {
        const dateObject = new Date(this.timeCreated);
        return `${dateObject.getDate()}/${dateObject.getMonth() + 1}/${dateObject.getFullYear()}`
    }
}
```

In component controller's ngOnInit()
this

```
this.productService.getProduct(this.productId).subscribe(product => {
  this.product = product;
});
```

The service

```
getProduct(id: number): Observable<Product> {
  return this.http.get<Product>(`${this.baseURL}/${id}`);
}
```

The view

```
{{product.timeCreatedDisplay}}
```

---

I tried setting timeCreatedDisplay function to return a fixed value and remove the API call (not calling the this.productService.getProduct...... line).
It worked and displayed the fixed value.

I also tried

```
this.productService.getProduct(this.productId).subscribe(product => {
  this.product = product;
  console.log(this.product.timeCreated)
  console.log(this.product.timeCreatedDisplay)
});
```

which give me undefined for timeCreatedDisplay and a correct value for timeCreated

So I suppose this is caused by the usage of http and observable?

Comment: `this.http.get<Product>('${this.baseURL}/${id}');` does not return the instance of class `Product`. It returns the Http response from the server, but you changed the generic type parameter. That has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Typescript, typing is structural before everything, so Typescript doesn't have a problem at all if you tell him that a javascript object is of a given type.

When you write:

```
this.http.get<Product>(`${this.baseURL}/${id}`);
```

Typescript understand: "trust me, the json object returned via http is indeed an instance of the class `Product`".

But in fact this is not true: it is just a js object created from the json and it doesn't really have the method `timeCreatedDisplay`.

If you want this to be true, you need to explicitly create an instance of `Product`, for example like this:

```
export class Product {
    constructor(private timeCreated: number) {}

    get timeCreatedDisplay () {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and then:

```
getProduct(id: number): Observable<Product> {
  return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseURL}/${id}`).pipe(map(j => new Product(j.timeCreated)));
}
```

Then you can improve on the and introduce an interface to define the structure of a JSON Product, use it in the `http.get` and have your class implement it if you desire so. And so on.

Comment: it should be `j.data.timeCreated` because `j` is a `Response` type.

Comment: thanks your method works!;;; @cgTag, I don't need .data and I think I need it only when I have options {observe: 'response'}

Comment: @cgTag actually not, when you type the `get` takes care of extracting the body and typing it correctly (in this case it is typed to `any` though).

Comment: @pk028382I discovered https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer that explains the problem well and provide a generic solution.